# How to show icons and text in Winforms ListView when View style is set to Details?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I just want to have 2 columns like:

```
Item                Value
[icon] Gold         10
[icon] Silver       2
[icon] Iron         1
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to have another column for the icons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look the documentation for the `SmallImageList` of the `ListView` control and the `ImageIndex` and `ImageKey` properties of the `ListViewItem` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.smallimagelist.aspx

Comment: Agreed with @matsolof

Answer (score 6):

In the first column images are supported by standard ListView, but for other columns, you will have to search the Internet, if I remember correctly there are a couple of codeproject controls that enable images in other columns (SubItems of ListView)

Comment: Thanks, I only need it for the first column.