# Display running Process Icons in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, process, icons, taskmanager

I’m new to programming so I apologies in advanced if I ask something stupid or use the wrong terminology.
I’m trying to find all the running processes (Like in Task Manager, "Applications") and list them in ListView with the icon.

I’ve been searching around and found lots of Q&A’s regarding this but I’m struggling to get it working.

Here's the part where I'm sure it's going wrong:

```
ImageList imageListSmall = new ImageList();
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theprocess.MainModule.FileName);
imageListSmall.Images.Add(ico);
lvAppProg.SmallImageList = imageListSmall;


ListViewItem itemProcess = new ListViewItem(theprocess.ProcessName);
itemProcess.SubItems.Add(theprocess.Id.ToString());
lvAppProg.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {itemProcess});
```

I’m trying to list each process with its ID and icon and from my understanding, all I need to do is create an “ImageList”, extract the icon location of the target “Process”, then add the small image icon to the ListView with the Process Name and ID.
(I don’t know if the icon needs to be in a separate column)
Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the Imagelist to the ListViewItem and set the imageindex like:

```
ListViewItem itemProcess = new ListViewItem(theprocess.ProcessName);
itemProcess.SubItems.Add(theprocess.Id.ToString());
lvAppProg.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {itemProcess});
itemProcess.ImageList = imageListSmall;
itemProcess.ImageIndex = YOURIMAGEINDEX
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
itemProcess.ImageList = imageListSmall;
I get this error in Visual Studio. 
“Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ImageList' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only”

Comment: Oh. Ok. Than you have to set the ImageList-Property at the ListView. You can also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312473/how-to-show-icons-and-text-in-winforms-listview-when-view-style-is-set-to-detail

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I actually found a new bug now that when I added this line:
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theprocess.MainModule.FileName);
Some of my processes go missing from the list view… which I don’t understand.